# Which Blendr Duo Base is compatible with the stem of the 2023 Trek Roscoe 8

Tags: stem, trek, bontrager

I own 2023 Trek Roscoe 8 https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/mountain-bikes/trail-mountain-bikes/roscoe/roscoe-8/p/35117/
Its stem is listed as:
`Bontrager alloy, 31.8mm, Blendr compatible, 7 degree, 50mm length`

I've got `Duo Base W537090` - https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/equipment/cycling-components/blendr-integration/pro-blendr/bontragerxxx/pro/elite-stem-blendr-duo-base/p/25909/

However it doesn't fit the stem. I searched Trek's site for the stem but couldn't find it.
Also looked at the Blendr compatibility guide at https://retailerassetsprd.blob.core.windows.net/techassets/BT22_MISC_Blendr_Flowchart_SEP22.pdf?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=r&se=2062-03-20T02:32:45Z&st=2019-03-19T18:32:45Z&spr=https&sig=UogJIteiFltPX66np2M0a3esSu1uZzABYHTFInUlT%2Fo%3D but couldn't find relevant info.

Which Blendr Duo Base is compatible with the stem of the 2023 Trek Roscoe 8?

Answer (score 1):

After chatting with the Trek site chatbot it seems the Legacy Blendr mount is the one compatible with the Roscoe 8 2023 stem https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/equipment/cycling-components/blendr-integration/comp-blendr/bontrager-comp-legacy-elite-stem-blendr-base/p/W540565/